# Python to parser a web page's images URLs

Tags: python, regex, urllib

This is my code to get a web page's image's URLs

for some webpage, it works very well, while it' dosen't work for some web page

this is my code:
    #!/usr/bin/python

```
import urllib2
import re
#bufOne = urllib2.urlopen(r"http://vgirl.weibo.com/5show/user.php?fid=17262", timeout=4).read()
bufTwo = urllib2.urlopen(r"http://541626.com/pages/38307", timeout=4).read()

jpgRule = re.findall(r'http://[\w/]*?jpg', bufOne, re.IGNORECASE)
jpgRule = re.findall(r'http://[\w/]*?jpg', bufTwo, re.IGNORECASE)
print jpgRule
```

`bufOne` work well, but `bufTwo`didn't work. so how to write a ruler for it to make bufTwo work well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Don't use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Rather use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to find all `img` tags and then get the `src` attributes.

```
from BeautifullSoup import BeautifullSoup

#...

soup = BeautifulSoup(bufTwo)
imgTags = soup.findAll('img')
img = [tag['src'] for tag in imgTags]
```

Comment: Thinks, but how to understand  `[tag['src'] for tag in imgTags]`

Comment: Its a list comprehension. `imgTags` is a list of `Tag` objects (look at the BeautifullSoup documentation for more info). The list comprehension makes a new list that will contain the values of all the `src` attributes. It is just a quick way of doing `img = []; for tag in imgTags: img.appent(tag['src'])`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take this chance ddk gave to show you an easier way of getting all the images.
Using Beautiful Soup like that:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
all_imgs = soup.findAll("img", { "src" : re.compile(r'http://[\w/]*?jpg') })
```

That will already give you a list with all the images you want.